# splitting counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

> How many even four-digit numbers can be formed from the digits 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, and 9 if each digit can be used only once?
>
> ```
> We consider the unit position by two parts, 0 or not 0.
>
> If the units position is 0 :
>  5 choices for the thousands positions,
>  4 choices for the hundreds positions,
>  3 choices for the tens positions.
> a total of   choices 60
> If the units position is not 0 :
>  4 choices for the thousands positions,
>  4 choices for the hundreds positions,
>  3 choices for the tens positions.
> a total of   choices. 96
> The total number of even four-digit numbers is 60 + 96 = 156
> ```

i dont understand why it was splitted into two parts.  i understand the first part (since if u fixed the units position to be 0, then theres 1 choice for it, and then the rest is simply n-1). For the second part, why was the thousand positions 4, not 5? isn't it he will just choose between (2 and 6) and then just use n-1 all the way. Also why was 4 repeated in the thousands and hundreds position? Thanks

Comment: This is not a probability problem so I have changed the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for spliting final $0$ from final non-$0$ is because of the problem of avoiding a leading $0$ combined with the final digit being even to make the whole number even.

You seem to have missed a line in the calculation of $96$:

> If the units position is not $0$ :
>
> - **$2$ choices for the units positions** *($2$ or $6$)*
> - $4$ choices for the thousands positions *($1$, $5$, $9$ and whatever is left from $2$ or $6$)*
> - $4$ choices for the hundreds positions *(the original six less the two already chosen)*
> - $3$ choices for the tens positions *(the original six less the three already chosen)*

Then $2 \times 4 \times 4 \times 3 = 96$ and you add the $60$ where the final digit is $0$ to get $156$.

Comment: i dont get the point why should the thousands be 4 choices instead of 5? after all, were only choosing only 1 in the units position (2 or 6) so the thousand should be 5?

Comment: @blackandyello: You are not allowed to choose $0$ as the thousands digit: you do not write *one hundred and twenty-six* as $0126$, but as $126$

Comment: oh yeah. tnx! Henry

Answer (score 1):

In the standard way of writing numbers, there are no four-digit numbers that begin with $0$.  Thus $0$ and the other two even digits we were given are not equivalent, $0$ is special.

That specialness can be dealt with in other ways.  For example, let us first count how many **strings** of four distinct digits there are such that the final digit is even.

The rightmost digit can be chosen in $3$ ways.  For *every* way of choosing the rightmost digit, there are $5$ ways to choose the next digit to the left, for a total of $3\cdot 5$ choices.  For *every* such choice, there are $4$ ways to choose the next digit to the left, for a total so far of $3\cdot 5\cdot 4$. And for every choice so far, there are $3$ ways to choose the next digit to the left, for a total of $3\cdot \cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$.  Multiply. We get $180$.

Our count of $180$, however, includes some **bad** strings, namely those that have leftmost digit $0$ and even rightmost digit. How many such bad strings are there? The rightmost digit can be chosen in $2$ ways (remember, the $0$ is already in front).  For *every* such choice, the next digit to the left can be chosen in $4$ ways. And for every one of the choices made so far, the next digit to the left can be chosen in $3$ ways, for a total of $2\cdot 4\cdot 3$. Multiply. We get $24$.

Thus the total number of even four-digit numbers is $180-24$.

**Another way:** We can split into cases in a way different from the one you were given. We split into two cases: (i) Leftmost digit is odd, and (ii) Leftmost digit is even.

In case (i), the leftmost digit can be chosen in $3$ ways. For *every* such choice, the rightmost digit can be chosen in $3$ ways. And for every one of these $3\cdot 3$ choices, there are $4\cdot 3$ ways to fill in the rest, for a total of $108$.

In case (ii), the leftmost digit can be chosen in $2$ ways. For every such choice, the rightmost digit can be chosen in $2$ ways. And for each of these $2\cdot 2$ choices, there are $4\cdot 3$ ways to fill in the rest, for a total of $48$.

Thus the total number of even four-digit numbers is $108+48$.

**Remark:** We try to explain "why split" further, by giving a **wrong** argument that *tries* to capture the specialness of $0$, but fails. The first (rightmost) digit can be chosen in $5$ ways. The last can be chosen in $3$ ways, and the rest can be chosen in $4\cdot 3$ ways, for a total of $180$.  What's wrong with this? Certainly it is true that there are $5$ choices for first digit. It is also true that there are $3$ choices for the last digit.  But it is **not** true that for *every* one of the $5$ choices of first digit, there are $3$ choices of last digit. If we choose an odd first digit, then yes, there are $3$ choices for the last.  But if we choose an even first digit, there are $2$ choices for the last. So the number of ways to choose first and last is not $5\cdot 3$. In fact it is $3\cdot 3+2\cdot 2$.