# How many even four-digit numbers can be formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 5, 6,$ and $9$ if each digit can be used only once?

Tags: combinatorics

First, I know this was posted first [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102929/splitting-counting-problem) but I reposted because the answer wasn't clear for me and the question is 8 years old so it's not getting any activity.

I don't understand the reason of the split, I first solved the problem in the following way:

Last digit: we have $3$ options: $0,2,6$ since we need the number to be even.

First digit: we have $4$ options: all minus $0$ and digit picked previously

Third digit: we have $4$ options: all minus the one picked in the previous $2$ digits.

Second digit: we have $3$ options: all minus previous $3$ digits.

so we get $3*3*4*4$

However I have a logical problem here, if I start analyzing in a different order (for example last digit to first) then it seems like I am getting different result (example:last digit has $3$ options and third one has $5$, etc...)

Moreover, I don't understand the solution and why they split it into these $2$ cases.

Comment: The answer is anything but correct, the correct value is [$156$](https://tio.run/##RcmxCsIwEAbgPU/xOwgJHJK2KnXIk5QMBVs8MLmQXAefPrq5ffCVj74kT3OpvXMqUhWsW1WRdzOlclZr2pHsgF0qGJz/fylbTYeuypKbXTxhIIyEG@FOeES6OvAOXnw8BY81P3@e4nkMwTvjev8C).

Comment: Recall, multiplication principle / rule of product  may be used when the number of available choices for each step does *not* depend on what choices were made in previous steps.  That is not the case here for you as the number of choices for the first digit depends on what choice was made for the last digit, either having four *or five* options.

Comment: Now... granted, you could temporarily ignore the restriction that zero may not be a leading digit and count the length-4 *strings*.  Then after done, we can then count how many of those were "bad" because of the erroneous leading zero.  That would give $3\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 - 1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 156$, the correct value.  (*The order of picking for the case where zero was leading digit I used was 1st digit, last digit, 2nd digit, 3rd digit*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we chose $0$ as the last digit, "the digit $0$" and "the digit picked previously" are the same digit, meaning that in this case, you have $5$ options for the first digit.

This is the reason for the split.

Comment: what about the order to follow?

Comment: This problem cannot be solve in this way without splitting cases, since the choice of the first digit affects the number of choices for the last digit, and vice versa.